# How to fix "the `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default" in Django API

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with creating new ratings for cars.
When i try to send a post request from Postman in order to create/add a new rating for a specific car i get the error:

`` The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. ``

These are my models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
symbol = models.CharField(max_length = 5)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    fuel = models.CharField(max_length = 1)##1 or 2 for fuel type
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(10),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ])
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.rating
```

My serializers:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ('id','name')

class TypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Type
        fields = ('id','name', 'fuel', 'car')
        #depth=2

class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = TypeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('id','rating', 'car', 'type')

    def create(self, validated_data):
    type_data = validated_data.pop('type')
    rating = Rating.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for t_data in type_data:
        Type.objects.create(rating=rating, **t_data)
    return rating
```

When i try to do a post request to rating such as :

```
{"rating":5, "car": 2,"type":{"id":1,"name":"OffRoad","fuel":"1","car":[{"id":2,"name":"Ford"}] } }
```

I get:

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
```

Please help if you can, ive been trying to fix this all day. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers The example on the docs will point you to the right direction towards fixing this issue.
The error message is literally describing the issue here though: DRF serializers do not support writable nested fields by default - and you have nested serializers (the `CarSerializer` inside your `TypeSerializer`, for example).

Comment: when i follow that it gives me a new error : NOT NULL constraint failed: api_rating.type_id

Comment: can you post your `create()`?

Comment: @Yellowduck i have added it to the above code

Comment: I have now added null=True to the ```type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)``` line however this now gives a new error of : ```create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str```